# Storing items assigned to different users

Tags: javascript, oop

Let's say I have a deck of 10 cards. They will all be different, but let's say 5 are "buy at 100, sell at 50" and the other 5 are "buy at 200, sell at 100"

I then have two people (as "person" objects) that will purchase the cards (picked at random from the deck) and at some point sell the cards.

I was thinking of storing each card as an object with `id`, `name`, `buyPrice`, `sellPrice` and `owner` and now I'm wondering what would be the best way to calculate which cards a person owns?

1) An array within the "person" obects that contains the ID of which cards they own, and when they buy/sell the card, it's added/removed from the array

2) When at a point where a person can sell a card, loop through the card objects and create a list of the ones that person owns.

3) An easier, more simple approach which I haven't thought of

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be:

3) Each card object has a `personId` field (or `person` reference) of the owner of the card (null if it doesn't have an owner). When the card is sold, you just update the PersonId

It's the opposite of 1), I think both are equivalent in effort if you need to list all the cards a person has, but you should evaluate that effort considering all your other requirements

Hope this helps, Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Since JavaScript objects are passed by reference, there's no reason not to store the actual card objects in the person's object.

```
Person.prototype.addCard = function (card) {
    this.cards.push(card);
};

Person.prototype.removeCard = function (card) {
    this.cards.splice( this.cards.indexOf(card), 1 );
};
```

So if `person1` buys `card1` from `person2`, you'll move it from one to the other:

```
person1.addCard(card1);
person2.removeCard(card1);
```